# PyCharm CE: Django Unexpected expression syntax

Tags: python, django, pycharm, syntax-error

I am doing the following code using PyCharm and Django and I'm getting the unexpected expression syntax error at the very end for ('products':products)) and I'm not sure why.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product

def admin_console(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products/products_page.html', ('products': products))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have meant to pass a dictionary literal as the `context` argument to `render`. Dictionary literals must be enclosed in curly braces. You've enclosed it in parentheses.

```
('products': products)
```

Vs.

```
{'products': products}
```